# How do I intercept and handle a Future in a decorator class?

Tags: java, multithreading, decorator, future

I'm decorating a class, and some of it's methods return a Future.  In one specific case, I'm interested in the result of the Future and would like to intercept it before notifying the caller.  Perhaps something like this:

```
public Future<Integer> getCalculation() {
  Future<Integer> future = realObject.getCalculation();
  // Get the result, store it somewhere
  // ???
}
```

In cases where getCalculation were synchronous, I could just call `realObject`, wait for a response, do whatever I want to with it, and then simply return it, like this:

```
public int getCalculation() {
  int result = realObject.getCalculation();
  this.cache = result;
  return result;
}
```

How do I apply this pattern for something that returns a Future?

Comment: If you want to get and store the results *before* you return, then what is the point of using a `Future`? You might as well just return the `int` now.

Comment: In my particular case, I want to capture a copy of the result before letting the client see it.  I want the calculation to happen in an async fashion, but I want first-dibs on the result.

Comment: Right... so you can still use a future to async it, but if you are capturing the result before you hand it off to the client you might as well return the int. Ill post an answer to try an clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I apply this pattern for something that returns a Future?

I think you have to implement your own proxy `Future` class here.  Maybe something like the following that delegates to the proxy:

```
public class FutureProxy implements Future<Integer> {
    private Calculator calculator;
    private Future<Integer> delegate;
    public FutureProxy(Calculator calculator, Future<Integer> delegate) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    // proxy all of the methods
    public boolean isDone() {
        return delegate.isDone();
    }
    ...
    // for get, you can then call back to `calculator`
    public Integer get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Integer result = delegate.get();
        calculator.setCachedCalculation(result);
        return result;
    }
    // need to handle get(long, TimeUnit) as well
    public Integer get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
          throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException;
        Integer result = delegate.get(timeout, unit);
        calculator.setCachedCalculation(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then your decorator getter would look like:

```
public Future<Integer> getCalculation() {
   Future<Integer> future = realObject.getCalculation();
   return new FutureProxy(this, future);
}
```

As you mention in the comments, if the `FutureProxy` is an inner class to the decorator, then the `Calculator` does not been to be injected.  Just make sure that you use `volatile` fields if the proxy is updating fields in `Calculator` that will be accessed by other threads.

Comment: I definitely do NOT want the decorator to block.  The background thread is an idea, but I don't want to have one thread per Future -- that doubles the amount of threading the system has to do.

Comment: This decorator is decorating a class that I have no control over.  I am not able to change the parent's return type.

Comment: Also:  callers will assume that they always get a Future back and that it adheres to the Future contract.

Comment: If the `FutureProxy` is an inner class of the decorator, then it eliminates the need to pass a reference of the decorator into the proxy.  I think this, so far, is the most elegant answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Good point @bstempi.  I forgot to mention that you need to make the fields that are updated be `volatile` if they are to be accessed in different threads.

Answer (score 2):

`SettableFuture` from the Guava library may come in handy : 
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html

You can indeed create a `SettableFuture` and assign to it your immediate value.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a proxy Future that you return from your decorator. Then you will need to implement the proxy Future's #get method to block until the real Future has returned, and you've been able to perform your work on the results.

```
class ProxyFuture<T> implements Future<T> {

    private Future<T> original;
    private Task task;
    ExecutorService executor;

    public ProxyFuture(Future<T> original, Runnable task, ExecutorService executor) {
        this.original = original;
        this.task = task;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        T result = original.get();
        executor.execute(task);
        return result;
    }


}
```

Here you have some application resource for your ExecutorService and have your Decorator create a Runnable that you pass to the new Future. This way your ProxyFuture will call the code in your Decorator before passing the results back to the original requestor.

Following is an example decorator

```
public class Decorator {

    Object original;

    public Decorator(Object original){
        this.original = original;
    }

    public void doDecoratedBehavior(){

    }

    public Runnable createTask(){
        return new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                doDecoratedBehavior();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to implement this without writing custom Future classes?  This idea came to me, but the writing of the Future classes was a negative.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to write a custom Future class? It's pretty simple.

Comment: You're right -- that's simple.  I take it that the `Runnable task` is meant to be a way for this proxy to let the decorator know that it's done?

Comment: I would have the Decorator have a method called #createTask that returns a Runnable, and in the #run method do the things with the references to your Decorator's member variables and methods that you desire.

Comment: @bstempi added Decorator example.

Comment: Question about this answer: is it creating a second thread to wait for the `originalObject` 's async response?  Am I creating a thread to wait for a thread?  Not that I have a problem with that; I'm just trying to better understand the answer.

Comment: The task runnable is being added to an ExecutorService which will run the operations on a separate thread. If you want to run the operations on the same thread, instead of calling ExecutorService#execute you could just call task#run on the currently executing thread.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your method must block...

```
public Future<Integer> getCalculation() {
  Future<Integer> future = realObject.getCalculation();

  // Get the result, store it somewhere
  //the .get() method is blocking...
  myInteger = future.get();

  return future;
}
```

And the caller code will immediately succeed in get()-ting the result...

**EDIT**

If non-blocking is desired, create a wrapper class for future

```
FutureWrapper<T> implements Future<T> {

    Future<T> wrapped;
    public FutureWrapper(Future<T> toBeWrapped) {
        wrapped = toBeWrapped;
    }

    public T get() {
        return wrapped.get();
    }

    //the other wrapper methods left out for sake of clarity
}


MyWrapper extends FutureWrapper<Integer>{

    //100% boilerplate
    public MyWrapper(Future<Integer> toBeWrapped) {
        super(toBeWrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        Integer value = super.get();
        //do the dirty stuff
        return value;
    }

}
```

**EDIT2**

If the "dirty stuff" involves fondling with the privates of the decorator (sorry, not native English :) (pun intended)), you can define the MyWrapper class inside the decorator class:

```
public MyDecorator {

    Integer dirtyStuff;


    public class MyWrapper extends FutureWrapper<Integer>{
        //boilerplate omitted
        public Integer get() {
            dirtyStuff= super.get();
            return dirtyStuff;
        }
}
```

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of the decorator.  It should not block.

Comment: @bstempi `to intercept it before notifying the caller` meant this to me... Might be my English though... Then codethulhu's solution is the way to go: create wrapper class, and implement the get() so that it does the dirty job...

Comment: To intercept before notifying the caller means that the decorator should know that the Future returned before the object that called into the decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the example!  The problem that I'm having is that `//do the dirty stuff` needs to happen within the decorator because the decorator will be the one "doing the dirty stuff," mainly because "dirty stuff" involves the decorator's private members.

Comment: @bstempi Well, it can be circumvented, if the MyWrapper is defined as non-static class **inside** the decorator class...

Comment: OoooOoooh, that's clever...I always get scoping of inner-classes confused.  I'll have to try this!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are describing, your asynchronization is pointless. Here is my psudo-code interpretation of what you are asking for -

```
Future<Integer> getCalculation(){
    Future<Integer> future = realObject.getCalculation();
    //asynch code runs while you presumably do other stuff.
    ....
    ....
    result = future.get();
    return future;
}
```

But at this point, using the future is pointless. The asynchronization saves you *no* time. Infact, it actually makes things take *longer* because of the extra overhead. This is because when you do `result = future.get()` you wait for the thread to finish, thus losing all the time you saved. It also means that returning the future gives no advantage because it cant do anything more than `result`.

In otherwords, this code would be faster and have less hassle (assuming you dont need to do anything during the calculation) -

```
Integer getCalculation(){
    return realObject.getCalculation();//assume it is rewritten to just return an int.
}
```

Comment: There are two responses to this.  Firstly, I can't change the return type of the parent method, so I'm stuck with `Future`.  Secondly, I don't want `getCalculation()` to block.  I want first dibs, but I don't want to have to wait for it.

Comment: @bstempi Not being able to change the return type sucks, but nothing can be done there. However, if you are not doing anything during `getCalculation()` then you have to wait anyways. The first block I wrote will get you first dibs, but you are still basically blocked, and you cant get around it if you insist on getting first dibs from what you are describing.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is an easy way to let the calculation run async and then to get called back so that I can get the result and modify the `Future` that was returned to the client.  I need first dibs, but I cannot block.